# Is data binding faster than modifying the properties of subcontrols manually?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So i have several subcontrols that need to take the value of the parent controls dependency property. Is binding the value to the dependency property of the parent going to be faster than just creating a callback method to occur when the parent's dependency property changes?

I was about to code it such that:

```
    ItemsControl ic = this.signal_viewer_item_control;
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(ic);
    foreach (var item in ic.Items)
    {
      ContentPresenter container = ic.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ContentPresenter;
      if (container != null)
      {
        SignalGraph sg = container.ContentTemplate.FindName("signal_graph", container) as SignalGraph;
        if (sg != null)
        {
          sg.GraphPenWidth = GraphPenWidth;
          sg.DrawSignals();
        }
      }
    }
```

so that I just manually modify the subcontrols graphpenwidth. Is it better to make that a dependency property and bind it to the parent's graphpenwidth value? i just thought that creating two dependency properties would be unnecessary overhead, but i'm wondering if there are benefits to having it in this situation

Edit: so i went back and tried to use dependency properties to compare the two, but then I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<wpfExp:SignalGraph 
    x:Name="signal_graph"
    Height="75"
    Signal="{Binding}" 
    signal_graph_window_width="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=signal_graph_window_width, Mode=OneWay}"
    X_Scale="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=X_Scale, Mode=OneWay}"
    MaxTimeValue="{Binding Source = {StaticResource ResourceKey=signal_data}, Path = MaxTimeValue, Mode=OneWay}">
  <wpfExp:SignalGraph.GraphPenWidth>
    <Binding ElementName="signal_box" Path="GraphPenWidth" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True">
    </Binding>
  </wpfExp:SignalGraph.GraphPenWidth>
</wpfExp:SignalGraph>
```

I put a two way binding on graph penwidth between the two properties and then registered the new properties like so:

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty GraphPenWidthProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("GraphPenWidth",
  typeof(int), typeof(SignalGraph),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new int(), new    PropertyChangedCallback(GraphPenWidthChanged)));
public int GraphPenWidth
{
  get
  {
    return (int)GetValue(GraphPenWidthProperty);
  }
  set
  {
    SetValue(GraphPenWidthProperty, value);
    default_pen = new Pen(Brushes.Green, value);
  }
}
private static void GraphPenWidthChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  SignalGraph sg = d as SignalGraph;
  sg.DrawSignals();
}
```

but on modification the graphpenwidthchanged callback method is never being called. I'm wondering does it have something to do with it being in an itemtemplate? any clue what could cause it not to update?

Comment: If you care about speed, why don't you measure it yourself?

Comment: [Race the horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I guess that's what I will do then. I just thought maybe it would be a common design question so someone might just know. My guess would be that dependency properties would be slower when you are just talking about relations to a parent object and don't have to traverse much through the visual tree.

Comment: All that horrible winforms-like code behind, and the use of `VisualTreeHelper.*()` is probably much slower than the beauty and maintainability of MVVM and databinding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont have tons of bindings to *different* dependency properties, difference in performance between binding and manual setter is not noticeable. Anyway, if you are going to use manual setter, searching element in template every time your property is being changed - is not a good idea. What about returning a custom control in the GetContainerForItemOverride and storing its template child (SignalGraph in your case) as a property (you can get it in the OnApplyTemplate using the GetTemplateChild method)?